# PHP: LIKE after space?

Tags: php, mysql

Right now i have a column called full_name where the first and last name gets stored. It is seperated by a normal space, so a name is stored like this: "Firstname Lastname". Now when im making this search users function, i have this:

```
$query = "SELECT full_name, id, user_name, sex, last_access, bostadsort FROM users WHERE full_name LIKE '$searchUser%'";
```

It works great by finding if you search by the firstname. I wish to make if you e.g type "lastname" then the user also will come up.

Now i find this quite my fault, that i started by having 1 column for the full_name and not firstname lastname columns.

So i wonder if i can do this without making two new columns and change rest of my code to work with firstname lastname new columns.. ?

Im using MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
full_name LIKE '$name%' OR full_name LIKE '% $name'
```

You should however split this column into two separate columns. What about multiple forenames/surnames?

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to get them in 2 separate fields. Otherwise use % wildcard as well in the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
... WHERE full_name LIKE '$searchUser%' OR full_name LIKE '%$searchUser' OR full_name LIKE '%$searchUser%'
```

will that do?

Answer (score 1):

Put a % in front of your variable to denote you want to match items at the end, a % in the back to denote you want to match the items in the front, and a  % in front and back to denote the item you want to match is in the middle.